# If A is open in a topological space $X$ , then $ A \cap \overline B \subseteq \overline {A \cap B} $

Tags: general-topology

If $A$  is open then ,

$$ A \cap \overline B \subseteq \overline {A\cap B} $$ 
How to prove it ??

Comment: A useful corollary is that if $A$ is open and $B$ is dense (that is, if $\overline B=X\,$) then $\overline A=\overline {A\cap B}.$ Proof: $\overline A=$ $ \overline {A\cap X}=$ $=\overline {(A\cap \overline B\,)}\subset$ $  \overline {\overline {A\cap B}}=$ $\overline {A\cap B}\subset$ $ \overline A.$

Answer (score 3):

Your proof (now deleted)  does not lead to an answer because you are proving that the complement of LHS is  a subset of something. For a correct proof pick $x \in A \cap \overline {B}$. Let $U$ be any open set containing $x$. Then $U\cap A$ is also an open set containing $x$. Since  $x \in  \overline {B}$ the open set $U\cap A$ must intersect $B$. Thus $A\cap U\cap B \neq \emptyset$. We have proved that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A \cap B$. This implies that $x$ belongs to RHS.